# How to animate letters in text using css3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I would like to animate small text, I want to display the letters one by one?

Is there any way to do it using CSS3?

Comment: [check this](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3RotatingWords/index5.html) out

Comment: I think u have to split letter by span and control it

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap your letters in a single tag, for example `span` and animate them.
W3C [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) has only `first-letter` pseudo class.

Comment: Yes, use javascript or better jQuery plugins(see other posts for plugins links)

Comment: @user1834809, It is true that css3 cannot yet apply pseudoclasses to a given letter, line nth-child. It is also true that for now you would have to wrap letters and apply animation to wrappers.

http://codepen.io/FWeinb/pen/djuIx

This is nth-letter plugin. You can then apply animation in css to any given letter in a word.

Answer (score 2):

Or check this keyframes animation

```
@-webkit-keyframes typing {
    from { width: 0 }
    to { width:16.3em }
}

@-moz-keyframes typing {
    from { width: 0 }
    to { width:16.3em }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink-caret {
    from, to { border-color: transparent }
    50% { border-color: black }
}

@-moz-keyframes blink-caret {
    from, to { border-color: transparent }
    50% { border-color: black }
}

body { font-family: Consolas, monospace; }

h1 { 
    font-size:150%;
    width:16.3em;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-right: .1em solid black;

    -webkit-animation: typing 17s steps(30, end), /* # of steps = # of characters */
                        blink-caret 1s step-end infinite;
    -moz-animation: typing 17s steps(30, end), /* # of steps = # of characters */
                        blink-caret 1s step-end infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://letteringjs.com/ is a plugin for jQuery which wraps every letter in a span tag to animate but keeps the html clean in the source. A good solution if you're already using jQuery, unfortunately there is no pure CSS solution as yet.

Answer (score 1):

I use textillate.js which depends on animate.css. It's super easy to get started with those two. From their docs:

```
<h1 class="tlt">My Title</h1>
```

And your JavaScript should look like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.tlt').textillate();
})
```

https://github.com/jschr/textillate
https://github.com/daneden/animate.css

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to display something letter by letter, you don't need jQuery or Textillate or any other plug-in. Just copy this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printLetterByLetter(destination, message, speed){
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById(destination).innerHTML += message.charAt(i);
        i++;
        if (i > message.length){
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, speed);
}

window.onload = function(){
    printLetterByLetter("someElement", "Hello world, bonjour le monde.", 100);
}
</script>
```

Replace 'someElement' by the id of the html element where the text is displayed. Replace '100' by any other number. Here it means a new letter appears every 100 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://www.hungry-media.com/code/jQuery/tickerType/

Css3 cannot do it on its own, you will need some script to slice characters one by one

Comment: @user1834809 Link that I have shared is using css, but css alone cannot solve your requirement. You need some scripting to make text dymanic